# Extract part of a webpage using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

> I have given an assignment to **create NFA and DFA** from **regex expression in Asp.Net**. I have found [this site](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa) doing exactly what i want. So I extracted that form

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa" method="post" name="regex-form">

<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="?">
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FItm0aR1x/fsXqOdi9ZXoB53+RvTxLlEVIAIcuKUKPs=">
  </div>
  
<label for="regex">Enter a regular expression: e.g. a*(b|cd)*</label>
<br>

<input id="regex" name="regex" onblur="restoreDefault(this, 'a*(b|cd?)+')" onclick="clearDefault(this, 'a*(b|cd?)+')" type="text" value="a*(b|cd?)+">
<br>

<input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Convert Regular Expression to NFA">

</form>
```

But when i `click` on that `button` it loads that full `website` but i only want these `two images NFA and DFA.`

> How could i prevent it from loading full page. and instead give me part of the DOM. I think it can be done using `AJAX`.

**Please bear with me**. I am new to web development but have some experience in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate an ajax html response in jQuery by wrapping the response in `$()` and performing jQuery methods on it.

```
$.get(url, function(html){
   // create jQuery object from response
   var $page = $(html);
   // find all images
   var $imgs = $page.find('img');
   // append those images to our container in main page
   $('#container').append( $imgs);
});
```

I used `$.get` shorthand method of `$.ajax`. Same thing can be done in `done()` callback of `$.ajax` or in `$.post`.

This could also be done using `load()` but you have more control over filtering the elements yourself within `$.get` or `$.ajax`

Update Using form post

```
$('form[name="regex-form"]').submit(function(e){
    // prevent default submit
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize(),
        url = $(this).attr('action');

    $.post( url, formData,  function(html){
       // create jQuery object from response
       var $page = $(html);
       // find all images
       var $imgs = $page.find('img');
       // append those images to our container in main page
       $('#container').append( $imgs);
    });

})
```

Comment: how do i post that as it is doing in form.  and where do you declare html

Comment: Going to have problem posting directly to that site with ajax due to `same origin policy`. Probably have to post to a proxy on your site and have it post to other site and return the response. I'll update with better form post code in question. I assumed you already had ajax working and were already receiving html back

Comment: I added the form submit. Would be better looking to give the form an ID and use id in submit selector. Can try it direct to other site but most likely will fail without proxy